Generate full property from a simple property with generator
I am trying to take a class like below with an [AutoSave] attribute:
[AutoSave]
public partial class GeneratedConfig : NotifiyingJsonSettings, IVersionable
{
    [EnforcedVersion("1.0.0.0")]
    public Version Version { get; set; } = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0);
    public override string FileName { get; set; } = $"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}GeneratedConfig.json";
    public virtual string TestString { get; set; }
    public virtual bool TestBool { get; set; }
}

which should generate following class (and my generator generate following class and I can see generated class in Dependency -> Analyzer -> LibName.AutoSaveGenerator):
public partial class GeneratedConfig : NotifiyingJsonSettings, IVersionable
{
    private System.Version version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0);

    [EnforcedVersion("1.0.0.0")]
    public System.Version Version
    {
        get => version;
        set
        {
            version = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Version));
            Save();
        }
    }

    private string fileName = $"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}NativeConfig.json";

    public override string FileName
    {
        get => fileName;
        set
        {
            if (fileName != value)
            {
                fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FileName));
                Save();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _testString;

    public string TestString
    {
        get => _testString;
        set
        {
            _testString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestString));
            Save();
        }
    }

    private bool _testBool;

    public bool TestBool
    {
        get => _testBool;
        set
        {
            _testBool = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestBool));
            Save();
        }
    }
}

But when I compile my app, I get some errors - for example:

The type 'GeneratedConfig' already contains a definition for 'FileName'
The type 'GeneratedConfig' already contains a definition for 'Version'
The type 'GeneratedConfig' already contains a definition for 'TestBool'
The type 'GeneratedConfig' already contains a definition for 'TestString'

I am using this generator code:
[Generator]
public class AutoSaveGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        var classesWithAttribute = context.SyntaxProvider
            .CreateSyntaxProvider(
                predicate: static (s, _) => s is ClassDeclarationSyntax cds && cds.AttributeLists.Count > 0,
                transform: static (ctx, _) => GetClassWithAttribute(ctx))
            .Where(static classWithAttribute => classWithAttribute is not null);

        context.RegisterSourceOutput(classesWithAttribute, (context, classInfo) =>
        {
            var generatedCode = GenerateClassWithAutoSave(classInfo);
            context.AddSource($"{classInfo!.ClassName}_AutoSave.g.cs", SourceText.From(generatedCode, Encoding.UTF8));
        });
    }

    private static ClassInfo? GetClassWithAttribute(GeneratorSyntaxContext context)
    {
        var classDeclaration = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
        var semanticModel = context.SemanticModel;

        var classSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration) as INamedTypeSymbol;

        if (classSymbol == null)
            return null;

        bool hasTargetAttribute = classSymbol.GetAttributes()
            .Any(attr => attr.AttributeClass?.Name == "AutoSaveAttribute" ||
                         attr.AttributeClass?.ToDisplayString() == "AutoSave.AutoSaveAttribute");

        if (!hasTargetAttribute)
            return null;

        var accessibility = classSymbol.DeclaredAccessibility.ToString().ToLower();

        // Collect property information
        var properties = classDeclaration.Members
            .OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>()
            .Select(p => new PropertyInfo
            {
                Name = p.Identifier.Text,
                Type = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(p.Type).Type?.ToDisplayString() ?? "object",
                IsVirtual = p.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.VirtualKeyword),
                IsOverride = p.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.OverrideKeyword),
                DefaultValue = p.Initializer?.Value.ToString(),
                Attributes = p.AttributeLists
                    .SelectMany(a => a.Attributes)
                    .Select(a => a.ToString())
                    .ToList()
            })
            .ToList();

        var baseTypes = GetBaseTypes(classSymbol);

        // Return class info with properties and base types
        return new ClassInfo
        {
            Accessibility = accessibility,
            ClassName = classSymbol.Name,
            Namespace = classSymbol.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString(),
            Properties = properties,
            BaseTypes = baseTypes
        };
    }

    private static List<string> GetBaseTypes(INamedTypeSymbol classSymbol)
    {
        var baseTypes = new List<string>();
        var currentBase = classSymbol.BaseType;

        while (currentBase != null && currentBase.ToDisplayString() != "object")
        {
            baseTypes.Add(currentBase.ToDisplayString());
            currentBase = currentBase.BaseType;
        }

        foreach (var iface in classSymbol.Interfaces)
        {
            baseTypes.Add(iface.ToDisplayString());
        }

        return baseTypes;
    }

    private static string GenerateClassWithAutoSave(ClassInfo classInfo)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Add required usings
        sb.AppendLine("using Nucs.JsonSettings.Modulation;");
        sb.AppendLine();

        // File-scoped namespace
        sb.AppendLine($"namespace {classInfo.Namespace};");
        sb.AppendLine();

        // Start class declaration with base types if any
        var baseTypeList = classInfo.BaseTypes;
        baseTypeList.Remove("Nucs.JsonSettings.JsonSettings");
        baseTypeList.Remove("JsonSettings");
        var baseTypesString = classInfo.BaseTypes.Count > 0 ? " : " + string.Join(", ", baseTypeList) : string.Empty;
        sb.AppendLine($"{classInfo.Accessibility} partial class {classInfo.ClassName}{baseTypesString}");
        sb.AppendLine("{");

        foreach (var prop in classInfo.Properties)
        {
            string fieldName = char.ToLower(prop.Name[0]) + prop.Name.Substring(1);

            // Generate private field with default value if it exists
            sb.AppendLine($"    private {prop.Type} {fieldName}" +
                (prop.DefaultValue != null ? $" = {prop.DefaultValue};" : ";"));

            // Add attributes if any
            foreach (var attribute in prop.Attributes)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"    [{attribute}]");
            }

            // Generate property
            sb.AppendLine($"    {(prop.IsOverride ? "public override" : "public")}" +
                $" {prop.Type} {prop.Name}");
            sb.AppendLine("    {");
            sb.AppendLine($"        get => {fieldName};");
            sb.AppendLine("        set");
            sb.AppendLine("        {");
            sb.AppendLine($"            if ({fieldName} != value)"); // Add the condition here
            sb.AppendLine("            {");
            sb.AppendLine($"                {fieldName} = value;");
            sb.AppendLine($"                OnPropertyChanged(nameof({prop.Name}));"); // Ensure OnPropertyChanged() is called
            sb.AppendLine("                Save();"); // Call Save() only if value changed
            sb.AppendLine("            }");
            sb.AppendLine("        }");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
        }

        sb.AppendLine("}");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private class ClassInfo
    {
        public string Accessibility { get; set; } = "public";
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
        public List<PropertyInfo> Properties { get; set; } = new();
        public List<string> BaseTypes { get; set; } = new();
    }

    private class PropertyInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool IsVirtual { get; set; }
        public bool IsOverride { get; set; }
        public string? DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public List<string> Attributes { get; set; } = new();
    }
}

How can I fix this duplicate property?

C# 13 (.NET 9) now allows partial properties. I don't know if there are already source generators using this brand new feature. But there might exist generators wrapping a field in a property (some exist for INotifyPropertyChanged).

c# 13 exist in net 9, but i need to support for net 8

You can actually use a newer language version with an older framework version. You can then use all the newer language features that are not dependent on a newer CLR or BCL version. (I am not sure if this the case for partial properties so.)

@OlivierJacot-Descombes For example, MVVM Community toolkit plans to improve their generator to use partial properties
